# Git: Differences since a commit

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Given this output:

```
c:\git\xxx>git log --oneline -n 5    
b99c981 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/xxx-newfeature' into xxx-blah
e53f30a [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
e40978b [maven-release-plugin] prepare release xxx-3.9.6
0639706 Modified Ant installion path
654ef47 [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
```

What are the GIT diff commands to see:

1. What changed in just commit 0639706
2. What changed in all commits
   since (and including) commit 0639706

Note I've been using `git difftool` to view the diffs visually (when I can figure out what I'm diff'ing..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, try

```
git show 0639706
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
git diff 0639706~1 0639706
```

For the the second one,

```
git diff 0639706~1
```

should do the trick. If you are only interested in seeing the file names, rather than the entire diff, you can use the `--name-only` option with either command.

Comment: Is there a way to see the results of git show visually?   Ie: instead of diff I can use difftool.  Is there an equivalent for show?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about show, but you could always diff the commit with the previous one, and just use difftool.

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "what changed" you mean "produce diff output detailing the changes":

> What changed in just commit 0639706

```
git show 0639706
```

> What changed in all commits since (and including) commit 0639706

```
git log -p 0639706
```

Comment: Note that `git diff` will show you the difference between 0639706 and the current state of the repository, while `git log -p` will show you patch output for each individual commit.